# Impact of adding members to Abstract Base Class in Java

Tags: java, deployment, abstract-class

I am a novice in Java, so the below question may look trivial.

**Background:**

Scenario 1:
I have a abstract base class `C1` in Java with say `N` interface member functions.
The client uses this class as a package and implements `Client1` the client business logic.
So `Client1` using the package `Package1` (which contains `C1` class definition) is able to work with jar `JAR1`.

Scenario 2:
I want to understand the impact of adding new member functions to class `C1`. The class `C1` with additional members (say we call `C2`) contains `N+M` member functions (which assume the client does not use) has jar file `JAR2`.

Now there can exists multiple combination of deployment -
`Client1` (built on `Package1`) runs in environment of `JAR1`
`Client1` (built on `Package1`) runs in environment of `JAR2`
etc

I am basically from a C++ background and there, the concept of vptr and its impact would be studied in details when a new interface is added to class which is exposed to clients.

**Question:**
a. How does these extension needs to be analyzed and implemented in case of JAVA (any material on the same is very helpful).
b. If this is a "safe option" in java, what are the other considerations we need to handle in such type of situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer both questions:

a) This article describes how the JVM loads and links class files:  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ConstantPool.doc.html.

b) As long as the signature of methods/public members doesn't change, calling code will still work.  Changing these will result in runtime exceptions when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood it right, your question is about the implication of modifying the interface.

Implementing an interface allows a class to become more formal about the behavior it promises to provide. Interfaces form a contract between the class and the outside world, and this contract is enforced at build time by the compiler.

```
interface Turns
{
   public void turnLeft();
   public void turnRight();
}

class Device implements Turns
{
   public void turnLeft()
   {
     //implementation
   }
   public void turnRight()
   {
     //implementation
   }
}
```

Now if we need to modify the interface. What we do is extend the interface.

```
interface TurnsAllWays extends Turns
{
   public void turnsBack();
}
```

So now Device can continue as it was or be modified if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, what if I add the new  `contract` in the existing interface itself (I know it would indicate poor initial design), but if so, what would be the impact?

Comment: Nothing would break until you recompile your files. It will throw a compile time error if you compile. `Device is not abstract and does not override abstract method turnsBack() in Turns`